# Possible to pull info from AdditionalProperties dictionary with Microsoft Graph PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use PowerShell Graph cmdlets instead of the Azure AD module cmdlets.  With the Azure AD module, I can do this:

```
# This is what I want:
get-azureadgroupmember -objectid $GroupID | select-object -property displayname, `
    mail, userprincipalname, objectid

DisplayName     Mail                        UserPrincipalName  ObjectId
-----------     ----                        -----------------  --------
John Smith      John.Smith@example.org      jsmith@example.org 4bae8291-6ec3-192b-32ce-dd21869ef784
(...)


# All of these properties are directly accessible in the returned objects:
$res = get-azureadgroupmember -objectid $GroupID
$res[0] | fl -prop *
# Shows long list of directly accessible properties
```

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent with PowerShell Graph:

```
$res = get-mggroupmember -groupid $GroupID
$res[0] | fl -prop *
# Only properties are DeletedDateTime, Id, and AdditionalProperties

# Want to do something like this, but it doesn't work:
get-mggroupmember -groupid $GroupID | select-object -property id, `
    additionalproperties['displayName'], additionalproperties['mail'], `
    additionalproperties['userPrincipalName']

# This works, but is there a better option???
get-mggroupmember -groupid $GroupID | foreach-object { `
        "{0},{1},{2},{3}" -f $_.id, $_.additionalproperties['displayName'], `
        $_.additionalproperties['mail'], $_.additionalproperties['userPrincipalName']
    }
```

AdditionalProperties is a dictionary (IDictionary) which contains displayname, mail, and userprincipalname.  My thought is there is probably a better way to do this or to get at the information.

There are a few interesting parameters in `Get-MgGroupmember` that I'm not clear on including `-ExpandProperty` and `-Property`.  I've tried playing around with these but haven't had any luck.  I'm wondering if there's a way to use these to do what I want.

Suggestions?

Comment: If `AdditionalProperties` is an `IDictionary`, unless the cmdlet has something built-in, you would need to loop through the key / value pairs and create an object out of it. What you're doing right now is converting the dict into a string which will not be easy to manipulate after

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I see what you're saying - could you provide an example of how you would create an object?  My ultimate goal is to export this into a CSV file which will be later imported into a database like construct.

Comment: Hope the answer gives you a hint on where to start

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Wow, that's great!  PowerShell is a second language for me.  I usually use Python.  I see what you mean, I just wasn't aware of that before.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the following `$object`, 3 properties and one of them `AdditionalProperties` is a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0):

```bash
$dict = [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[object, object]]::new()
$dict.Add('displayName', 'placeholder')
$dict.Add('mail', 'placeholder')
$dict.Add('userPrincipalName', 'placeholder')

$object = [pscustomobject]@{
    DeletedDateTime      = 'placeholder'
    Id                   = 'placeholder'
    AdditionalProperties = $dict
}
```

Supposing from this object you're interested in `Id`, `displayName` and `mail`, you could use [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) with [calculated properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject):

```bash
$object | Select-Object @(
    'Id'
    @{
        Name       = 'displayName'
        Expression = { $_.additionalProperties['displayName'] }
    }
    @{
        Name       = 'mail'
        Expression = { $_.additionalProperties['mail'] }
    }
)
```

However this gets messy as soon as you need to pick more property values from the objects, [`PSCustomObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) with a loop comes in handy in this case:

```bash
$object | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Id          = $_.Id
        displayName = $_.additionalProperties['displayName']
        mail        = $_.additionalProperties['mail']
    }
}
```

Both alternatives would output the same *"flattened"* object that can be converted to Csv without any issue:

- As Object

```bash
Id          displayName mail
--          ----------- ----
placeholder placeholder placeholder
```

- As Csv

```
"Id","displayName","mail"
"placeholder","placeholder","placeholder"
```

In that sense, you could construct an array of objects using one of the above techniques, for example:

```bash
Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $GroupID | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Id                = $_.id
        displayName       = $_.additionalproperties['displayName']
        mail              = $_.additionalproperties['mail']
        userPrincipalName = $_.additionalproperties['userPrincipalName']
    }
}
```

If you're looking for a *programmatical way* to flatten the object, you can start by using this example, **however it's important to note that this can only handle an object which's property is nested only once**, in other words, it can't handle recursion:

```bash
$newObject = [ordered]@{}
foreach($property in $object.PSObject.Properties) {
    if($property.Value -is [Collections.IDictionary]) {
        foreach($addproperty in $property.Value.GetEnumerator()) {
            $newObject[$addproperty.Key] = $addproperty.Value
        }
        continue
    }
    $newObject[$property.Name] = $property.Value
}
[pscustomobject] $newObject
```

The output from this would become a flattened object like this, which also, can be converted to Csv without any issue:

```bash
DeletedDateTime   : placeholder
Id                : placeholder
displayName       : placeholder
mail              : placeholder
userPrincipalName : placeholder
```

It's also worth noting that above example is not handling possible *key collision*, if there are 2 or more properties with the same name, one would override the others.

---

Bonus function that should work with the objects returned by the cmdlets from [Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0), [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) and [Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-8.3.0) Modules. This function can be useful to flatten their `` Dictionary`2 `` property. It only looks one level deep if the property value implements [`IDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-6.0) so don't expect it to flatten any object. For the given example should work well.

```bash
function Select-GraphObject {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, DontShow)]
        [object] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string[]] $Properties = '*'
    )

    begin {
        $firstObject = $true
        $toSelect    = [Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
    process {
        if($firstObject) {
            foreach($property in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties) {
                foreach($item in $Properties) {
                    if($property.Value -is [Collections.IDictionary]) {
                        foreach($key in $property.Value.PSBase.Keys) {
                            if($key -like $item -and $key -notin $toSelect.Name) {
                                $toSelect.Add(@{
                                    $key = { $_.($property.Name)[$key] }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        continue
                    }

                    if($property.Name -like $item -and $property.Name -notin $toSelect) {
                        $toSelect.Add($property.Name)
                    }
                }
            }
            $firstObject = $false
        }

        $out = [ordered]@{}
        foreach($item in $toSelect) {
            if($item -isnot [hashtable]) {
                $out[$item] = $InputObject.$item
                continue
            }
            $enum = $item.GetEnumerator()
            if($enum.MoveNext()) {
                $out[$enum.Current.Key] = $InputObject | & $enum.Current.Value
            }
        }
        [pscustomobject] $out
    }
}
```

Using copies of the `$object` from above examples, if using the default value of `-Properties`, the example objects would be *flattened*:

```bash
PS /> $object, $object, $object | Select-GraphObject

DeletedDateTime Id          displayName mail        userPrincipalName
--------------- --          ----------- ----        -----------------
placeholder     placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder
placeholder     placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder
placeholder     placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder
```

Or we can filter for specific properties, even Keys from the `AdditionalProperties` Property:

```bash
PS /> $object, $object, $object | Select-GraphObject Id, disp*, user*

Id          displayName userPrincipalName
--          ----------- -----------------
placeholder placeholder placeholder
placeholder placeholder placeholder
placeholder placeholder placeholder
```

Comment: Nice answer, I hope I would have found this sooned! Comment: Multiple modules ships `ConvertTo-FlatObject` cmdlet that does flattening for deeper objects