# Display hashtable values from MsGraph output

Tags: powershell, formatting, hashtable

Many MsGraph commandLets output a property called AdditionalProperties that contains a hashtable that can be used to perform searches within its values. For example:

```
Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId 6774992b-24c1-4df6-95aa-7edc66bb4d70 | Where {$_.AdditionalProperties['displayName'] -like "BlaBlaBla*"} | FL

DeletedDateTime      :
Id                   : b11f441c-cbb1-435a-bb0a-ff6aad6143e3
AdditionalProperties : {[@odata.type, #microsoft.graph.group], [createdDateTime, 2018-06-11T10:05:49Z], [creationOptions, System.Object[]], [description, BlaBlaBla
                       BlaBlaBla], [displayName, BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla], [groupTypes, System.Object[]], [mailEnabled, False], [mailNickname,
                       eec66659-b0e2-4304-89b0-556d000854b8], [proxyAddresses, System.Object[]], [renewedDateTime, 2018-06-11T10:05:49Z], [resourceBehaviorOptions,
                       System.Object[]], [resourceProvisioningOptions, System.Object[]], [securityEnabled, True], [securityIdentifier,
                       S-1-12-1-1215998234-1267435052-2566001834-3259707894], [onPremisesProvisioningErrors, System.Object[]]}
```

I am wondering if there is a way, in a simple command, to output a Formated Table using the Id property of the object and some of the pairs key/value from the AdditionalProperties hashtable, something like:

```
Id                                    displayName         mailEnabled
--                                    -----------         -----------
b11f441c-cbb1-435a-bb0a-ff6aad6143e3  BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla  False
```

Any contribution is welcome. Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards.

Edit:

If I replace `| FL` with `| Select -Expand AdditionalProperties` the output is just a table with the pairs of the hashtable:

```
Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId 6774992b-24c1-4df6-95aa-7edc66bb4d70 | Where {$_.AdditionalProperties['displayName'] -like "atic.azure.licenzas*"} | Select -Expand AdditionalProperties

Key                          Value
---                          -----
@odata.type                  #microsoft.graph.group
createdDateTime              2018-06-11T10:05:49Z
creationOptions              {}
description                  BlaBlaBla BlaBlaBla
displayName                  BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla
groupTypes                   {}
mailEnabled                  False
mailNickname                 f1dac475-4371-4558-8f85-929fc7846b69
proxyAddresses               {}
renewedDateTime              2018-06-11T10:05:49Z
resourceBehaviorOptions      {}
resourceProvisioningOptions  {}
securityEnabled              True
securityIdentifier           S-1-12-1-1215998234-1267435052-2566001834-3259707894
onPremisesProvisioningErrors {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72385655/15339544

Comment: What happens if you replace `| FL` with `|Select -Expand AdditionalProperties`?

Comment: To @SantiagoSquarzon, it partially answers my question but does not comply with the "simple" requirement.

Comment: To @MathiasR.Jessen, it simply shows a table with hashtable pairs:

Comment: @LuisA. Please [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73542815/edit) and add the additional info there :)

Comment: I'm not sure what more "simple" than `Select-Object` can you expect from powershell. That's as simple as it gets with a built-in cmdlet

Comment: something like that `Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId 6774992b-24c1-4df6-95aa-7edc66bb4d70 | Where {$_.AdditionalProperties['displayName'] -like "BlaBlaBla*"} | Select id, @{E={$_.additionalProperties['displayName']}},@{E={$_.additionalProperties['mailEnabled']}}` (which is litterally the suggestion from Santiago, but without relabeling the value to shorting the code) ?

Comment: I have included a function to the answer posted above to make it even easier, if that answers your question I believe this can be closed for Duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the flatten method offered by Santiago, another way is to use the `Invoke-MgGraphRequest` which allow the `-OutputType` parameter to send back a PSObject instead of a Hastable (or Json or HttpResponseMessage).

```
Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri "/v1.0/users/6774992b-24c1-4df6-95aa-7edc66bb4d70/memberOf?`$select=id,displayName,mailEnabled" -OutputType PSObject | select -expand value | select id, displayName, mailEnabled
```