PowerShell - AzureAD Report SAM Account Name Pull
I am using the below code in PowerShell to create a CSV file from Azure AD which lists our North America users and some of their account properties. The current code works great. However, I am trying to add an additional column/property to the report to pull the SAM Account Name
param(
    [string] $path = "C:\Temp\ADUsersNA-$(Get-Date -format 'MM-dd-yyyy').csv"
)
 
 Connect-AzureAD
 
$userData = @()
 
foreach ($azuser in Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "accountEnabled eq true" | Where-Object { $_.Country -eq "United States" -or $_.Country -eq "Canada" }) {
    $manager = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $azuser.ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $managerEmail = if ($manager) { $manager.UserPrincipalName } else { "" }
 
    $userData += [pscustomobject]@{
        "Employee ID"   = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
        "First Name"    = $azuser.givenName
        "Last Name"     = $azuser.surname
        "Work Email"    = $azuser.UserPrincipalName
        "Job Title"     = $azuser.JobTitle
        "Company"    = $azuser.CompanyName
        "Manager Email" = $managerEmail
        "City"          = $azuser.City
        "Country"       = $azuser.Country
    }
}
 
$userData | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation

So far, under the "Country" row I tried using:
"SAM Name"     = $azuser.SamAccountName
"SAM Name"     = $azuser.ExtentionProperty["SamAccountName"]
"SAM Name"     = $azuser.ObjectID["SamAccountName"]

None of the above solutions have been able to successfully pull SAM Account name to the CSV file.

if you're using graph call instead of AzureAD, the attribute would be onPremisesSamAccountName. No idea in AzureAD, this module is old and will soon be deprecated, you should stop using it

perhaps this answer helps you find it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384632/possible-to-pull-info-from-additionalproperties-dictionary-with-microsoft-graph/72385655#72385655

Is your on-prem users is synced with azure? If you are getting null value for SAM Account Name in your csv file, it indicates that this attribute is not being synchronized from your on-premises AD, or it doesn't exist in Azure AD.

@Pmocha Is this below solution works for you?

Note: The SAM Account Name is related to on-premises. If you want to fetch the SAM account name, you need to synchronize the on-premises users with Azure AD.
I agree with @Santiago Squarzon, Azure AD PowerShell module is old and going to be deprecated soon. So, try using Microsoft Graph PowerShell module instead of Azure AD
Here is my powershell script,
param(
    [string] $path = "<filepath>$(Get-Date -format 'MM-dd-yyyy').csv"
)

# Clear $userData array to start fresh
$userData = @()

# Connect to Microsoft Graph
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "User.ReadBasic.All", "Directory.Read.All"

# Fetch all users with onPremisesSyncEnabled and onPremisesSamAccountName
$users = Get-MgUser -Filter "onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true" -All -Property "id, givenName, surname, userPrincipalName, jobTitle, companyName, city, country, onPremisesSamAccountName"

# Filter users who have onPremisesSamAccountName
$filteredUsers = $users | Where-Object { $_.onPremisesSamAccountName -ne $null }

foreach ($azuser in $filteredUsers) {
    # Get the manager's information
    $manager = Get-MgUserManager -UserId $azuser.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $managerEmail = if ($manager) { $manager.UserPrincipalName } else { "" }

    # Use the Extension property
    $employeeId = $azuser.AdditionalProperties['extension_EmployeeId'] 

    $userData += [pscustomobject]@{
        "Employee ID"   = $employeeId
        "First Name"    = $azuser.givenName
        "Last Name"     = $azuser.surname
        "Work Email"    = $azuser.UserPrincipalName
        "Job Title"     = $azuser.JobTitle
        "Company"       = $azuser.CompanyName
        "Manager Email" = $managerEmail
        "City"          = $azuser.City
        "Country"       = $azuser.Country
         "SAM Account Name" = $azuser.OnPremisesSamAccountName
    }
}

# Export data to CSV
$userData | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation

Output:

